# case selection based on pregmatch

Tags: php

I have a form that when a url is placed in the form and the button is clicked the URL is process and based on the pregmatch it extracts a URL. When a match is found for one of them the others return an error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` how can i make it so that if a match is found for one the others are not giving an error?

```
if ( !isset( $_GET['go'] ) ) return;
$userLink =  $_GET['go'] ;
if ( !$userLink ) return;

$data = file_get_contents($userLink);
preg_match("@^(?:\s)*var url = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed1);
preg_match("@^(?:\s)*self.location = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed2);
preg_match("@^(?:\s)*window.location = \"(.*)\";@mi",$data, $parsed3);
preg_match("@^(?:\s)*Lbjs.TargetUrl = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed4);
preg_match("@^(?:\s)*linkDestUrl = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed5);

echo 'var.url - ' . $parsed1[1] . '<br>';
echo 'self.location - ' . $parsed2[1] . '<br>';
echo 'window.location - ' . $parsed3[1] . '<br>';
echo 'Lbjs.TargetUrl - ' . $parsed4[1] . '<br>';
echo 'linkDestUrl - ' . $parsed5[1];
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the input string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming only one of the URL types is going to match, not two or more?

```
if ( !isset( $_GET['go'] ) ) return;
$userLink =  $_GET['go'] ;
if ( !$userLink ) return;

$data = file_get_contents($userLink);

$array = array(

  'var url',
  'self.location',
  'window.location',
  'Lbjs.TargetUrl',
  'linkDestUrl',

);

foreach ($array as $value)
{

  if (preg_match("@^(?:\s)*($value) = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed))
  {
    break;
  }

}

echo $parsed[1] . ' - ' . $parsed[2] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check whether the element is set before printing:

```
echo 'var.url - ' . (isset($parsed1[1]) ? $parsed[1] : 'not found') . '<br>';
echo 'self.location - ' . (isset($parsed1[2]) ? $parsed[2] : 'not found') . '<br>';
echo 'window.location - ' . (isset($parsed1[3]) ? $parsed[3] : 'not found') . '<br>';
echo 'Lbjs.TargetUrl - ' . (isset($parsed1[4]) ? $parsed[4] : 'not found') . '<br>';
echo 'linkDestUrl - ' . (isset($parsed1[5]) ? $parsed[5] : 'not found');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the result of `preg_match`, which will return 0 if no matches are found. From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1

Something like:

```
if(preg_match("@^(?:\s)*var url = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed1)) {
  if(!empty($parsed1[1])) { echo 'var.url - ' . $parsed1[1] . '<br>'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a @ before each of your preg_match statements.  @ suppresses error messages, so be careful where you use it.

`@preg_match("@^(?:\s)*var url = '(.*)';@mi",$data, $parsed1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("@^(?:\s)*(var url|self.location|window..location|Lbjs.TargetUrl|linkDestUrl) = ['\"](.*)[\"'];@mi", $data, $parsed)) {
   echo $parsed[1], " - ", $parsed[2];
} else {
   echo "no matches found at all";
}
```